# Why is Entity Framework not bringing relationship collections?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linq, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I am learning EF and making some code, and I have this relationship below.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c931833c7c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/c931833c7c.png)

When I try to do:

```
var users = from u in db.Users
            where u.Name.StartsWith("F")
            select u;

if(users.Count() > 0)
{
     var dto = users.First();
}
```

The user 'Fabio' is returned, but the area count is 0. He has a relationship with an area, actually.

Doesn't EF bring relationships automagically? Or is something important missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Include](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx):

```
var users = from u in db.Users.Include("Areas")
            where u.Name.StartsWith("F")
            select u;
```

Also change this code:

```
if(users.Count() > 0) // executes query
{
    var dto = users.First(); // executes it again
}
```

to:

```
var dto = users.FirstOrDefault(); // execute once
if (dto != null)
{
    // ...  
}
```